# how to calculate to get data using servqual formula in codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have the data to be calculated using the servqual formula.
Servqual quality = perceptions - expectations / total users

First, I calculate all the active criteria

Second, I count all the users who answered the questionnaire

Third, I calculate all perceptions and expectations to get the sum of each.

Fourth I do multiplication for expectations. Because expectations are inputted by the admin. So expectations multiplied by the number of users.

Then I do the calculation with total perception minus the expectations divided by total user

Then servqual results, I update on the answer colomn in the result_jawab table.

Then I will display it according to the criteria and the results.

this my code. i dont know this code not work. please any body help me.

this image i attach for 2 table

[image]

[image]

function hasil_servqual(){
    $jml_kriteria_aktif=$this->db->where('aktif','Y')->count_all_results("kriteria");

```
$kuisioner_aktif=$this->db->query("SELECT * FROM kuisioner WHERE aktif='Y'");
$aktif_kuisioner=$kuisioner_aktif->row();

$tenant=$this->db->query("SELECT id_tenant FROM hasil_kuisioner WHERE NOT id_tenant='0' AND id_kuisioner=$aktif_kuisioner->id_kuisioner");
$jumlah_tenant=$tenant->num_rows();

$persepsi= $this->db->query("SELECT SUM(jawaban) AS j_p FROM detail_jawaban WHERE id_kuisioner=$aktif_kuisioner->id_kuisioner");
$jumlah_persepsi= $persepsi->result_array('j_p');

$ekspektasi= $this->db->query("SELECT SUM(jawaban) AS j_e FROM detail_jawaban WHERE id_tenant='0' AND id_kuisioner=$aktif_kuisioner->id_kuisioner");
$jmlh_ekpektasi= $ekspektasi->result_array('j_e');
$jumlah_ekspektasi=("");
print_r($jumlah_ekspektasi);

    $query=$this->db->query("SELECT * FROM kriteria WHERE aktif='Y' ORDER BY id_kriteria");
    if ($query->num_rows()>0) {
        $data=$query->result_array();
        foreach ($data AS $value) {
            $this->hasil.="<tr>";
            $this->hasil.="<td>$value[id_kriteria]</td>";
            $this->hasil.="<td>$value[kriteria]</td>";
            $this->hasil.="</tr>";

        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Please post the schema of the tables along with a comment on each column and table describing its purpose/use. Hard to tell what's what with the code shown.

Comment: ok aplogyze for this mistake.